# Heroku Gunicorn Procfile

Tags: python, heroku, flask, gunicorn

I have a hard time finding documentation for creating Procfiles using flask with gunicorn and Heroku. Somewhere I found that the syntax is:
`web: gunicorn my_folder.my_module:app`. But I can't make it work. It only works for me when my python script: `hello.py` is in the root folder of the app. When I put it in a subfolder called app and create a Procfile: `web: gunicorn app.hello:app` it doesn't work. Only when I use `web: gunicorn hello:app` and my python script is in the root folder. Can someone explain me the proper syntax of Procfiles for gunicorn on Heroku, and how to make it work when the python script is in a subfolder?

Comment: Have you added the `__init__.py` file to the the app folder to make it a Python module?

Comment: No haven't added that..

Comment: And it works when you add that file?

Comment: And is that an empty folder or should it contain some code?

Comment: Just an empty file is Ok, but I am guessing here, I don't know Heroku nor how Procfile works, I just know that python requires `__init__.py` to see a folder as a Python package.

Comment: Have a look at [this template](https://github.com/zachwill/flask_heroku). It has a Procfile and is ready to be pushed to Heroku. You can learn from it, or just fork it and base your app on the template.

Comment: You put `unicorn` in your Procfile instead of `gunicorn`.

Comment: No that was the bloody autocorrect that did that.. In my post.

Answer (score 35):

Gunicorn takes a flag, `--chdir`, that lets you select which directory your Python app lives in.  So, if you have a directory structure like:

```
my-project/
  Procfile
  my_folder/
    my_module.py
```

and `my_module.py` contains:

```
app = Flask(__name__, ...)
```

You can put the following in your `Procfile`:

```
web: gunicorn --chdir my_folder my_module:app
```

Comment: your comment save me for many hours of debugging ! kudos  can you explained well how my_module:app works?

Comment: Expanded my answer.

Comment: `web: gunicorn app:app`

The first `app` represents the name of the python file that runs your application or the name of the module it is in. The second `app` represents the app name that is named in your .py file. Just wanted to add because it helps clarify the contents of the procfile and it's syntax. E.g. your appname would be my_awesome_app in the following code: `if __name__ == '__main__':`
    `my_awesome_app.run()`

Comment: Do we have a provision to add the port number here as well? Example: `web: gunicorn wsgi:app   port:8080`

Comment: This is finally what solved my problem when trying to deploy to Heroku and getting the H10 error. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You may try Hypercorn as it is successor of Gunicorn 
Modify your Procfile as follows :

```
web: hypercorn -b 0.0.0.0:$PORT Path_To_Your_File:app
```